# How to make groups of symbols bold with Mathjax

Tags: mathjax, typesetting

I want to be able to make several symbols bold by grouping them within some sort of bolding command.  I can make a single symbol bold by using (for example)

```
\boldsymbol \phi
```

but I want to be able to bold several symbols, something like:

```
{\boldsymbol \phi \vee \psi}
```

This doesn't work.  I've tried `\bf` in a group as well, which Mathjax says it supports, but it doesn't.

How can I achieve this, I don't want to have to put `\boldsymbol` on every single symbol!

Comment: It's too bad that people on the [***LaTeX***](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) branch of stack exchange delete all questions about ***MathJax***. ***LaTeX*** programmers are the  people who are mostly likely to know how to do something in  ***MathJax***.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\boldsymbol{\phi \vee \psi}`.  Note that `\boldsymbol` is a macro that takes an argument (like `\mathbf{}`), not a switch (like `\bf`).  Also, note that in TeX, `\bf` only affects certain symbols (basically, just the letters and numbers), and MathJax does the same.  So in TeX, as well as MathJax, `{\bf \phi \vee \psi}` will produce the same thing as `\phi \vee \psi`.